# Who will review my first text coding which resulted in indentation error?

Tags: python-2.7, indentation

```
def classify0(inX, dataSet, labels, k):
    dataSetSize = dataset.shpe[0]
    diffMat = tile(inX, (dataSetSize, 1)) - dataSet
    sqDiffMat = diffMat ** 2
    sqDistances = sqDiffMat.sum(axis = 1)
    distances = sqDistances ** 0.5
    sortedDistIndicies = distances.argsort()
    classCount={}
    for i in range(k):
        voteIlabel = labels[sortedDistIndicies[i]]
        classCount[voteIlabel] = classCount.get(voteIlabel, 0) + 1
    sortedClassCount = sorted(classCount.interitems(),
                              key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=true)
    return sortedClassCount[0][0]
```

above is my first coding using python. I imported it to terminal and it say 'IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level'. But I don't know how to fix it. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You code at:</strike>

```
    sortedClassCount = sorted(classCount.interitems(),
                          key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=true)
    return sortedClassCount[0][0]
```

<strike>seems to jump for no reason. Just remove all the extra spaces like so:</strike>

```
    sortedClassCount = sorted(classCount.interitems(),
    key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=true)
    return sortedClassCount[0][0]
```

In python since there are no queerly brackets `{}` to signify starts and end of functions the interpreter uses indentation level to know the difference.
This is why your code doesn't work.

try deleting all indentation and putting it back because you might have mixed spaces with tabs or you have accidentally added another space to a place you shouldn't have one.

Comment: That line is just more parameters to the `sorted` function. It is fine to indent that continuation line in any manner the coder likes. More likely has mixed spaces and tabs.